# Is numerical approximation the only option when derivative cannot be expressed explicitly as an expression?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

My problem is the following: Are there any **differentiable functions** on $\Bbb R$ for which we don't know or can't find an explicit expression for the derivative? So is approximating the derivative numerically the only choice?

Comment: Given a differentiable function we can always compute the derivative by difference quotients. Sometimes we have to.

Comment: in process of proving anything is differentiable you calculate the derivative. You calculate the left hand derivative and the right hand derivative and if they are equal that is the derivative and the function is differentiable.

Comment: There are differentiable functions for which we can't write an expression for the function itself (but for obvious reasons it's rather difficult to mention an example). In those cases we can't find an expression for the derivative either.

Comment: @BadEnglish If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Comment: @BadEnglish https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean that we can't find an explicit expression of the first derivative, then yes, they do exist. Take $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ as

$$f(x)=\int_0^x \left(\int_0^t e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}dy\right)dt.$$ Then, it can be proved that

$$f'(x)= \int_0^xe^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}dy.$$ However, this function cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions. That being said, you can always approximate the derivative numerically. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [neat trick involving dual numbers](https://blog.demofox.org/2014/12/30/dual-numbers-automatic-differentiation/) (a number system that has a nonzero infinitesimal element $\epsilon$ such that $\epsilon^2=0$), that lets you numerically calculate derivatives of any function that you can numerically calculate in the first place, to machine precision. This procedure is no less exact than determining an analytical expression for the derivative and computing the value of that expression numerically.

Comment: looks amazing, thanks

Answer (score 0):

For functions on $\Bbb R$: derivability $\iff$ differentiability.

**NOTE**
That’s not the case for functions of several variables for which only one direction is true: differentiability $\implies$ derivability.

Comment: What do you mean by "derivability"? I don't see what your first statement is supposed to mean and why it should be true.

Comment: it means that exists finite the limit $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ for $h\to 0$

Comment: I see...but I guess that was not what the question asked for, because he asked for explicit expressions, see the answer by Magnusseen.